# Change stickman's head to my professor's head in Qt Stickman example

Tags: c++, qt, vector-graphics

I'm messing around with Qt and I saw [this demo](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/animation-stickman.html). Now, I'm trying to figure out how I can change the head from a regular stick figure head to a picture of my professor's head (let's assume I have a .png file called profHead.png).

The code in stickman.cpp is below:

```
#include "stickman.h"
#include "node.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QTimer>

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

static const qreal Coords[NodeCount * 2] = {
    0.0, -150.0, // head, #0

    0.0, -100.0, // body pentagon, top->bottom, left->right, #1 - 5
    -50.0, -50.0,
    50.0, -50.0,
    -25.0, 50.0,
    25.0, 50.0,

    -100.0, 0.0, // right arm, #6 - 7
    -125.0, 50.0,

    100.0, 0.0, // left arm, #8 - 9
    125.0, 50.0,

    -35.0, 75.0, // lower body, #10 - 11
    35.0, 75.0,

    -25.0, 200.0, // right leg, #12 - 13
    -30.0, 300.0,

    25.0, 200.0, // left leg, #14 - 15
    30.0, 300.0

};

static const int Bones[BoneCount * 2] = {
    0, 1, // neck

    1, 2, // body
    1, 3,
    1, 4,
    1, 5,
    2, 3,
    2, 4,
    2, 5,
    3, 4,
    3, 5,
    4, 5,

    2, 6, // right arm
    6, 7,

    3, 8, // left arm
    8, 9,

    4, 10, // lower body
    4, 11,
    5, 10,
    5, 11,
    10, 11,

    10, 12, // right leg
    12, 13,

    11, 14, // left leg
    14, 15

};

StickMan::StickMan()
{
    m_sticks = true;

    // Change this to true to get zombie
    m_isDead = false; // Do you know what happens when a zombie is struck by lightning?
                     // It gets knocked the f*** out.


    // Change this to a different picture (get prof's picture off facebook)
    // Hmmm... maybe not.. thought it would have been simpler...
    m_pixmap = QPixmap("images/head.png");


    m_penColor = Qt::white; // white -- change to something else
    m_fillColor = Qt::black; // black -- change to something else

    // Set up start position of limbs
    for (int i=0; i<NodeCount; ++i) {
        m_nodes[i] = new Node(QPointF(Coords[i * 2], Coords[i * 2 + 1]), this);
        connect(m_nodes[i], SIGNAL(positionChanged()), this, SLOT(childPositionChanged()));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<BoneCount; ++i) {
        int n1 = Bones[i * 2];
        int n2 = Bones[i * 2 + 1];

        Node *node1 = m_nodes[n1];
        Node *node2 = m_nodes[n2];

        QPointF dist = node1->pos() - node2->pos();
        m_perfectBoneLengths[i] = sqrt(pow(dist.x(),2) + pow(dist.y(),2));
    }

    startTimer(10);
}

StickMan::~StickMan()
{
}

void StickMan::childPositionChanged()
{
    prepareGeometryChange();
}

void StickMan::setDrawSticks(bool on)
{
    m_sticks = on;
    for (int i=0;i<nodeCount();++i) {
        Node *node = m_nodes[i];
        node->setVisible(on);
    }
}

QRectF StickMan::boundingRect() const
{
    // account for head radius=50.0 plus pen which is 5.0
    return childrenBoundingRect().adjusted(-55.0, -55.0, 55.0, 55.0);
}

int StickMan::nodeCount() const
{
    return NodeCount;
}

Node *StickMan::node(int idx) const
{
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < NodeCount)
        return m_nodes[idx];
    else
        return 0;
}

void StickMan::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
{
    update();
}

void StickMan::stabilize()
{
    static const qreal threshold = 0.001;

    for (int i=0; i<BoneCount; ++i) {
        int n1 = Bones[i * 2];
        int n2 = Bones[i * 2 + 1];

        Node *node1 = m_nodes[n1];
        Node *node2 = m_nodes[n2];

        QPointF pos1 = node1->pos();
        QPointF pos2 = node2->pos();

        QPointF dist = pos1 - pos2;
        qreal length = sqrt(pow(dist.x(),2) + pow(dist.y(),2));
        qreal diff = (length - m_perfectBoneLengths[i]) / length;

        QPointF p = dist * (0.5 * diff);
        if (p.x() > threshold && p.y() > threshold) {
            pos1 -= p;
            pos2 += p;

            node1->setPos(pos1);
            node2->setPos(pos2);
        }
    }
}

QPointF StickMan::posFor(int idx) const
{
    return m_nodes[idx]->pos();
}

//#include <QTime>
void StickMan::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *)
{
  /*  static int frames = 0;
    static QTime time;
    if (frames++ % 100 == 0) {
        frames = 1;
        time.restart();
    }

    if (time.elapsed() > 0) {
        painter->setPen(Qt::white);
        painter->drawText(0, 0, QString::number(frames / (time.elapsed() / 1000.0)));
    }*/

    stabilize();
    if (m_sticks) {
        painter->setPen(Qt::white);
        for (int i=0; i<BoneCount; ++i) {
            int n1 = Bones[i * 2];
            int n2 = Bones[i * 2 + 1];

            Node *node1 = m_nodes[n1];
            Node *node2 = m_nodes[n2];

            painter->drawLine(node1->pos(), node2->pos());
        }
    } else {
        // first bone is neck and will be used for head

        QPainterPath path;
        path.moveTo(posFor(0));
        path.lineTo(posFor(1));

        // right arm
        path.lineTo(posFor(2));
        path.lineTo(posFor(6));
        path.lineTo(posFor(7));

        // left arm
        path.moveTo(posFor(3));
        path.lineTo(posFor(8));
        path.lineTo(posFor(9));

        // body
        path.moveTo(posFor(2));
        path.lineTo(posFor(4));
        path.lineTo(posFor(10));
        path.lineTo(posFor(11));
        path.lineTo(posFor(5));
        path.lineTo(posFor(3));
        path.lineTo(posFor(1));

        // right leg
        path.moveTo(posFor(10));
        path.lineTo(posFor(12));
        path.lineTo(posFor(13));

        // left leg
        path.moveTo(posFor(11));
        path.lineTo(posFor(14));
        path.lineTo(posFor(15));

        painter->setPen(QPen(m_penColor, 5.0, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
        painter->drawPath(path);

        {
            int n1 = Bones[0];
            int n2 = Bones[1];
            Node *node1 = m_nodes[n1];
            Node *node2 = m_nodes[n2];

            QPointF dist = node2->pos() - node1->pos();

            qreal sinAngle = dist.x() / sqrt(pow(dist.x(), 2) + pow(dist.y(), 2));
            qreal angle = asin(sinAngle) * 180.0 / M_PI;

            QPointF headPos = node1->pos();
            painter->translate(headPos);
            painter->rotate(-angle);

            painter->setBrush(m_fillColor);
            painter->drawEllipse(QPointF(0,0), 50.0, 50.0);

            painter->setBrush(m_penColor);
            painter->setPen(QPen(m_penColor, 2.5, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));

            // eyes
            if (m_isDead) {
                painter->drawLine(-30.0, -30.0, -20.0, -20.0);
                painter->drawLine(-20.0, -30.0, -30.0, -20.0);

                painter->drawLine(20.0, -30.0, 30.0, -20.0);
                painter->drawLine(30.0, -30.0, 20.0, -20.0);
            } else {
                painter->drawChord(QRectF(-30.0, -30.0, 25.0, 70.0), 30.0*16, 120.0*16);
                painter->drawChord(QRectF(5.0, -30.0, 25.0, 70.0), 30.0*16, 120.0*16);
            }

            // mouth
            if (m_isDead) {
                painter->drawLine(-28.0, 2.0, 29.0, 2.0);
            } else {
                painter->setBrush(QColor(128, 0, 64 ));
                painter->drawChord(QRectF(-28.0, 2.0-55.0/2.0, 57.0, 55.0), 0.0, -180.0*16);
            }

            // pupils
            if (!m_isDead) {
                painter->setPen(QPen(m_fillColor, 1.0, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
                painter->setBrush(m_fillColor);
                painter->drawEllipse(QPointF(-12.0, -25.0), 5.0, 5.0);
                painter->drawEllipse(QPointF(22.0, -25.0), 5.0, 5.0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was reading through this code and I saw this line:

```
m_pixmap = QPixmap("images/head.png");
```

And I was thinking "Sweet! I can just change the source of that file to a .png of my prof's head and it'll all work out perfectly!"

However, I couldn't find where this file was at. Then I looked at the bottom of the code and saw how the head was actually drawn/filled.

Can someone explain how I can change this stickman's head to a .png of my prof's head? I'm somewhat familiar with C++ now, but this is my first time playing with Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code it looks like head is drawn using various paint method, not using pixmap.

I suspect that following position is where head is supposed to be drawn.

```
 QPointF headPos = node1->pos();
```

if you draw your pixmap here, using QPainter drawPixmap method, i guess it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where the original picture is. Just give it the name of the new file and make sure it is in the same location as the executable. (Or provide the full path to the file like e.g. "C:/users/me/picture.png"

Comment: Although the image is loaded, I don't think it is actually used in that example project - i.e. nothing is done with m_pixmap. In this case, loading a different image file won't do anything at all.

Comment: @tmpaerce You are right. Silver should best try Kunal's answer.